# Android: Delete record from remote database on app uninstall

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have written an application ([AirQApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turnkey.airqapplication&hl=en_GB)) for general public as well as for our customers. When customers log in with the given username and password, it stores the `device registration ID` in the central database to generate gcm notifications for the specific customer similarly when they logout it deletes the device ID, but when they uninstall this application, it cannot delete the device ID from the database hence notifications are still generated.

I googled it and it seems like it is not possible to perform a task on application uninstall.
Is there any other solution which can be applicable in my scenario? 
Is there any way to check if the application is installed on a particular device from device registration ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I googled it and it seems like it is not possible to perform a task on application uninstall

Correct.

> Is there any other solution which can be applicable in my scenario?

The next time you try to send a message to that GCM registration ID, [GCM should tell you that it is no longer registered](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#response).

Comment: Thanks for the documentation and you are right, notification was not sent. I thought I tried to send a message after deleting the app and did get the notification but I was wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The end user uninstalls the application.
> 2. The 3rd-party server sends a message to GCM server.
> 3. The GCM server sends the message to the device.
> 4. The GCM client receives the message and queries Package Manager about whether there are broadcast receivers configured to receive it,
>      which returns false.
> 5. The GCM client informs the GCM server that the application was uninstalled.
> 6. The GCM server marks the registration ID for deletion.
> 7. The 3rd-party server sends a message to GCM.
> 8. The GCM returns a NotRegistered error message to the 3rd-party server.
> 9. The 3rd-party deletes the registration ID.

From [Here](http://support.airbop.com/kb/faq/how-does-gcm-handle-app-uninstalls)